# Should I use 就 in when translating "when you say it like that, I feel confused", e.g. ...我就感到困惑?

Tags: grammar

If I want to say "When you say it like that, I feel confused" would it be "你这么说的时候，我就感到困惑"? Also, if I just wanted to say "saying it like that makes me confused" would that be "这么说让我感到困惑"? Trying to get a feel for how sentences are constructed. Thanks.

Comment: The sentences you made are correct.

Comment: I would probably omit 的時候 in the first sentence, because the “When” is not really about time. The 就 fits nicely in that sentence.

Comment: or use 当 at the start instead: 当你这么说，我就。。。（study samples at jukuu)

Comment: it stresses the reason or the moment.

Answer (score 2):

In short:

你这么说的时候，我**就**感到困惑.
**Whenever** you say it like that, I feel confused.

你这么说的时候，我(会)感到困惑.
**When** you say it like that, I feel confused.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to one of my previous answers: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/21973/13501

## 就

It is used to denote the word in which the speaker do not want the listener to make mistakes or misunderstandings.

While the mistake the listener may make will be,

1. The listener will think MORE THAN the expected or correct one.
2. Response with opposition the NEGATIVE thought by someone else. (Not applicable in your case)

Ex: 这就是台湾。 -> Here is Taiwan.

Taiwan is not far away, it is right here. However, using 就, it could meaning the following 3 things:

i. The listener may think Taiwan is still far away.
ii. The listener thinks Taiwan is still far away.
iii. The speaker wants the listener to know Taiwan is NOT far away, but right here.

Based on the interpretations above, for your sentence:

你这么说的时候，我就感到困惑。

The meaning should be interpreted as:

I will feel confused as long as you say it like that. (Don't think that I need more conditions to be confused, this condition suffices)

Answer (score 0):

In short: 就 means AND. Yes, just AND with a salt of "already". There are many ANDs in chinese, each AND marks different flavors of english AND.
就 must be used in cases where you want to stress consequece of an action. Like: *"Do X **and** I do Y."* which should be translated as

*"Do X, I 就 do Y" Here 就 serves as *logical-consequence-AND*. That means there are two interpretations for this sentence:

1. I will do Y because of your doing **X** (and not Z).
2. I will do Y because of your **doing** X (and I was just waiting for this time to come, so I'll do my Y right after you)"*

In English you can also drop AND from the sentence:

*"Do X, I do Y."*

The meaning has ALMOST not changed but, by dropping **stressed and** (mind you it's not any AND), you've intrioduced a couple of new interpretations to the sentence. That is,

1. You do X, I do Y but my doing Y has nothing to do with you doing X, it's just a consequence. There is no logical relation between us doing our thing.
2. You do X and I do Y becuase you do X.
3. You do X and I do Y after you do X.
   By dropping explicit steress on AND you maximize the entropy of your message here, that is, there are more interpretations now then was befor with **stressed and**.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you should add 就.
I am a nativie Chinese. Believe me .I don't feel good when I read the sentence 你这么说的时候，我就感到困惑.